# Creating a Directory in azure storage with REST API

Tags: java, rest, azure

I'm trying to create a directory using REST API. Below is the code for Signature. Can you help me to find the issue in the code:

```
string storageKey = 'storage key';
string storageName = '<storageName>';
Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
string formattedDate = dt.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')+ ' GMT';
system.debug('formattedDate--'+formattedDate);

string CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-date:'+formattedDate+'\nx-ms-version:2016-05-31';
string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>\nrestype:directory';
string StringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\n\n\napplication/xml;charset=utf-8\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' + CanonicalizedHeaders+'\n'+CanonicalizedResource;
system.debug('StringToSign--'+StringToSign);

Blob temp = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',Blob.valueOf(StringToSign),temp ); //StringToSign
system.debug('oo-'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac));
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('PUT');
req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/xml;charset=utf-8');
req.setHeader('content-length', '0');
req.setHeader('x-ms-version','2016-05-31' );
req.setHeader('x-ms-date', formattedDate);
string signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac);
string authHeader =  'SharedKey <storageName>'+':'+signature;

req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);
req.setEndpoint('https://<storageName>.file.core.windows.net/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>&restype=directory');

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res= http.send(req);
```

Refer the link for azure documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-directory

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: @GauravMantri Updated the code.

Comment: Please change this line of code `req.setEndpoint('https://<storageName>.file.core.windows.net/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>\nrestype=directory');` to `req.setEndpoint('https://<storageName>.file.core.windows.net/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>?restype=directory');` and see if this fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Also, change the following line of code `string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>\nrestype=directory'` to `string CanonicalizedResource = '/' + storageName + '/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>\nrestype:directory'`.

Comment: Sorry Gaurav, I pasted wrong code.i tried above format. But, it didn't helped me.

Comment: You still have issue in this line of code: `req.setEndpoint('https://<storageName>.file.core.windows.net/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>&restype=directory');`. Please try again by changing it to `req.setEndpoint('https://<storageName>.file.core.windows.net/<myShareName>/<DirectoryName>?restype=directory');`

Comment: Thank you. Tried the same. But no luck.

Comment: Can you read the response stream in your error? You would see more details about the error. If there's an error related to string to sign mismatch, please edit your question and include the string to sign you're computing and the one used by server (this you should get from the error message.

Comment: Thank You for the help @GauravMantri After having your valuable suggestions i re-written my code which is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following java code for your reference, and it works well for me.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.utils.Base64;

public class CreateDirectory {

    private static final String account = "jaygong";
    private static final String key = "******";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
        String urlString = "http://" + account + ".file.core.windows.net/testshare/testdirectory?restype=directory";
//      Proxy proxy = new Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888)); 
//      URL serverUrl = new URL(urlString);  
//      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection(proxy);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
        getFileRequest(connection, account, key);
        connection.connect();
        System.out.println("Response message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("Response code : " + connection.getResponseCode());

        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getErrorStream())));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
        }
        System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
    }

    public static void getFileRequest(HttpURLConnection request, String account, String key) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
        String stringToSign = "PUT\n" + "\n" // content encoding
                + "\n" // content language
                + "\n"// content length
                + "\n" // content md5
                + "\n" // content type
                + "\n" // date
                + "\n" // if modified since
                + "\n" // if match
                + "\n" // if none match
                + "\n" // if unmodified since
                + "\n" // range
                + "x-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\n" // headers
                + "/" + account + request.getURL().getPath()+"\nrestype:directory"; // resources
        System.out.println("stringToSign : " + stringToSign);
        String auth = getAuthenticationString(stringToSign);
        System.out.println(auth);
        request.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");
        request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
    }

    private static String getAuthenticationString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
        String authKey = new String(Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        String auth = "SharedKey " + account + ":" + authKey;
        return auth;
    }

}
```

***Notes:***

Please note that `System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");` in the above code is necessary.
I found a parameter called `allowRestrictedHeaders` from [source code](http://javasourcecode.org/), which was originally designed to limit the use of Http Header for security in the design of API.All of the following are limited:

```
private static final String[] restrictedHeaders = {
    /* Restricted by XMLHttpRequest2 */
    //"Accept-Charset",
    //"Accept-Encoding",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "Connection", /* close is allowed */
    "Content-Length",
    //"Cookie",
    //"Cookie2",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
    //"Date",
    "Expect",
    "Host",
    "Keep-Alive",
    "Origin",
    // "Referer", 
    // "TE",
    "Trailer",
    "Transfer-Encoding",
    "Upgrade",
    //"User-Agent",
    "Via"
    };

    allowRestrictedHeaders = ((Boolean)java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new sun.security.action.GetBooleanAction(
            "sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders"))).booleanValue();
```

Hope it helps you.